# Format labels produced by cut() with thousands separator

Tags: r

I used the cut function to bin my numbers. Is there a way to apply comma separator, preferably with thousands separator so the labels won't come out as exponential?

[image: dummy data]

```
df<-df_RFM_complete %>% mutate(monetary.class=cut(monetary,breaks=c(seq(25,10000,150),359086),format_fun = format, sep = ", ")) %>% group_by(monetary.class) %>% summarise(count=n())
```

Comment: `prettyNum(1234567, big.mark=",")` ([`?prettyNum`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/formatc.html)).

Comment: is `cut` being masked from some package? I don't recognize the `format_fun` argument

Comment: perhaps [`kimisc`](https://github.com/krlmlr/kimisc/blob/master/R/cut.R)?